# How to remove fields from the 'New Lead Pagelayout'

Tags: page-layout, record-type, leads

When creating a new lead, I want only a handful fields  on the 'New Lead' page layout.

[image]

Setup > Customize > Leads > Page Layout > Edit  removes the fields from the Detail page layout.

I see there are 50 custom fields on our New Lead page layout. These are redundant fields we no longer use.
How to remove fields from the 'New Lead Pagelayout'

Comment: Are you saying that you've already deleted the fields from the page layout, but the fields are still appearing on the New Lead screen?  Have you checked in Setup if the New button has been overridden with a custom Visualforce page or Lightning component?

Comment: Is it that you don't want the users to be able to add data on those "extra fields", but you want to keep them on the detail so that old records can display their data? Or is it that you want to have more fields in the page detail than in the "new" form?

Comment: @David Cheng No to your question.  When i go to the Leads Tab , and click New , the page layout that pops up to create a new lead has three custom sections with custom fields. I want to remove all of these custom sections and custom field from the 'New'  page layout.  This should be straight forward, just as it is when editing the Detail page. However I don't know how.

Comment: @Sergio Alcocer, yes  I want to have more fields in the page detail than in the "new" form.  At the time of lead creation only company name, phone, name should suffice. When a call is made to the lead, and as the lead progresses through the various stages, the 'other data' is gathered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, the `New Page Layout`, the `View Page Layout` and the `Edit Page Layout` are practically the same (when using the standard), however you could have some work-arounds to achieve something similar to what you describe. The ones that come to my mind right now are:

1. You could have two record-types in the Lead object (eg. `New` and `Existing`). Have one Page Layout assign to each of them and allow users to create only Leads of type `New`. Then, have an Automation (Process Builder, Before-Flow, WorkFlow, Trigger...) to change the record Type from `New` to `Existing` when saving.
2. You could configure a Global Action with the few fields that you want and train your users to use the Global Action.
3. (Not applicable to your current situation) If you would be using a custom object, you could use `Dynamic Forms` and hide certain fields / sections based on an `Advanced Criteria` such as `Created By > Username not equals`

From this point on, if none of the above proposals fit your needs, you can always override the `New` or `View + Edit` Actions. Make sure you read the restrictions about the overrides before going through it. As an example, If you override the `New` action, it will NOT override the "modal" that shows up when creating fields by a Lookup, which means that the view with all the fields will show up. (Maybe here you are safe because you might have not so many objects pointing to Lead, but just keep the restrictions in mind).

Also, "advanced" users could use the `nooverride=1` on the url to bypass your component and go through the standard layout, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The New function uses the same page layout as view and edit.  If you want a different layout for New, you'll have to build a create record Quick Action (which uses its own layout), or write a custom Lightning component.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Sergio's approach #3 should work even for objects that are not custom. I got it to work on the Opportunity Object for example. I documented it here, https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000JfmWPSAZ Be sure to read my two comments, the 2nd of which gives a step by step walk-through of the approach I think Sergio was suggesting.

Comment: Salesforce has a pretty bad track record when it comes to breaking links. Please reproduce the solution and explanation here so that this answer can still be useful after Salesforce decides to break links (or rebrand) again.

Comment: In Lightning App Builder:
    Click "Set Field Visibility" or "Set Component Visibility"
    Click "add Filter"
    Click "Advanced"
    Click "Select" (next to Field)

In the "Select field" interface:
    Click drop down arrow and select "Record." A new "Type to filter list" box should appear
    Click drop down arrow and select "Created By." A new "Type to filter list" box should appear 
     Click drop down arrow and select "Username."
    Click "Done" 

In filter interface:
    Set Operator to "Not Equal"
    Type '' (two apostrophes, not one quote symbol.)
    Click "Done"